# Trying to prevent direct IP access Nginx SSL

Tags: nginx, proxy, reverse-proxy

I've been searching for the answer here regarding the following code:

```
server {
   listen 443 ssl;
   server_name "host.domain.com";

   location / {
            proxy_pass http://host.domain.com;

            }

    ssl_certificate      /etc/httpd/ssl/Sample_StarCert.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key  /etc/httpd/ssl/Sample-NPW.key;

    }
```

This does what it's supposed to do for the most part by reverse-proxying SSL requests to an http server on the same machine for host.domain.com requests (by design).

The problem arises when I try to access the same site https://ipaddress

Now the browser accessing the site in this manner is confronted with a certificate warning.  I need that certificate warning to go away under these circumstances and to either get that attempt blocked, or redirected to a FQDN request.  Either is fine.

I've been trying to accomplish this with other server blocks, but the problem I keep running into is that SSL server blocks seem to really want to begin presenting the certificate to the browser before processing the request which is strange to me since I thought SNI (which this server is compiled with) is designed to recognize the request before presenting a certificate is necessary?  It's very likely I just misunderstand how this all works and would welcome the guidance.

I tried conditional statements with no success as well.  Any ideas?

Comment: The certificate warning will not go away. `https` requires a valid certificate and you do not have a valid certificate for its IP address. The best you can achieve is redirect to FQDN **after** user accepts certificate warning.

Comment: I was afraid of that.  It's interesting . . . I know Nginx is looking at the browser request before it serves up the certificate because it is serving up one certificate for the FQDN request, and a different one for the non FQDN request as I wanted but as you pointed out, it seems to really want to complete the certificate transaction before anything else such as preventing what I'm trying to prevent (rightfully so it seems).  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I've often seen this attempt for port 80:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name _;
    return 444;
}
```

However, this won't work for SSL and cause your website from not being accessible when requesting through the domain.

I figured out, you can simply check if the http host is the server name in the primary server block for SSL, like so:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name YOUR_DOMAIN;
    index index.php index.html;
    root /var/www/html/;

    # block direct IP access
    if ($http_host != $server_name) {
        return 444;
    }
}
```

This attempt also works for HTTP, if you prefer some consistency.